# How to load SUBSET of large Oracle table into Dask dataframe?

Tags: dask

Here's what I tried:

```
dask_rf = dd.from_pandas(pd.read_sql('select ...)', conn_cx_Oracle), npartitions = 10)
```

This gives me a 'large object' warning and recommends using client.scatter.  Problem is that it appears that client.scatter requires data to be loaded into a Pandas dataframe first, which is why I'm using Dask in the first place because of RAM limitations.

The Oracle table is too large to read using Dask's read_sql_table because read_sql_table does not filter the table in any way.

Ideas?  Dask not applicable to my use case?

Edit - Per answer below and after researching how to do so, here is my attempt to convert to use sqlalchemy expression:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, MetaData, select

sql_engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@environment')

metadata = MetaData(bind=sql_engine)

table_reference = Table('table', metadata, autoload=True, schema='schema')

s = select([table_reference ]).where(table_reference .c.field_to_filter == filtered_value)

import dask.dataframe as dd

dask_df = dd.read_sql_table(s, 'sqlalchemy_connection_string', 'index_col', schema = 'schema')

dask_df.count()
```

> Dask Series Structure: npartitions=1 action_timestamp    int64
>   vendor_name           ... dtype: int64 Dask Name: dataframe-count-agg,
>   1996 tasks

```
dask_df.count().compute()
```

> DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02391: exceeded
>   simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

Why trying to connect to Oracle?

Edit #2 - Just in case helpful, I have performed additional tests.  I wanted to prove that sqlalchemy worked on its own so I proved that via:

```
result = sql_engine.execute(s)

type(result)
```

> sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy

```
result.fetchone()
```

> *Results were displayed*

This seems to rule out SQLAlchemy/Oracle issues, so any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same thing right now.

To not being stuck... You may not have enough RAM but you possible have a lot of free storage. So... a suggestion for now

```
# imports
import pandas as pd 
import cx_Oracle as cx
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Connection stuff
...
conn = ...

# Query
qry = "SELECT * FROM HUGE_TABLE"

# Pandas Chunks
for ix , chunk in enumerate(pd.io.sql.read_sql(qry , conn , ... , chunksize=1000000)):
    pd.DataFrame(chunk).to_csv(f"chunk_{ix}.csv" , sep=";") # or to_parquet 

# Dask dataframe reading from files (chunks)
dataset = dd.read_csv("chunk_*.csv" , sep=";" , blocksie=32e6) # or read_parquet
```

Since this is IO intensive and you are performing sequential operations, it may take a while.

My suggestion to "export" quicker is to partition your table and perform the chunk export in parallel by each partition.

Comment: thanks.  i'll take a look.  i've also been able to work around it by exporting table to csv and loading csv to dask but of course that is not automated.  i reported a bug and have been asked to create a minimal bug report which i don't have time for ATM but will report back here when I can finally get to the bottom of it.  in the meantime, i haven't seen anyone successful load dask from oracle so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is that it appears that client.scatter requires data to be loaded into a Pandas dataframe first

That is because you are calling Pandas code here

```
dd.from_pandas(pd.read_sql('select ...)', conn_cx_Oracle), npartitions = 10)
#              pd.read_sql('select ...)', conn_cx_Oracle) # <<-----
```

According to the [`read_sql_table` docstring](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table)
you should be able to pass in a SQLAlchemy expression object.

The reason that `read_sql_table` doesn't accept arbitrary SQL query strings, is because it needs to be able to partition your query, so each task loads only a chunk of the whole. This is a tricky thing to do for the many dialects out there, so we rely on sqlalchemy to do the formatting.

Comment: Converted to use slqalchemy expression.  Please see edited question for details.

Comment: Please see Edit #2 in question for test that SQLAlchemy/Oracle appear to be functioning properly.