# How to read large table fast in Python

Tags: python, oracle, performance

I'm trying to read a large table from Oracle database and save it as local csv file in Python 3. Here's my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

user = 'me'
password = 'password'
dsn = 'dsn'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, dsn)

for chunk in pd.read_sql("select col_a, col_d, col_s from my_table", con, chunksize=10**4):
    chunk.to_csv(r"my_path\my_file.csv", index = false)
```

However, given the table has 200k+ rows, and I'm selecting a dozen columns out of 80+ columns, the performance of the code above is literally crawling.

Is there a faster way to read the table and save it as csv?

Comment: why involve pandas at all? Almost certainly, the DBMS has an efficient way to export the results of a query to a CSV, involving python, especially pandas, isn't going to make things fast.

Comment: Presumably you shouldn't do file I/O in every iteration of the loop, only once at the end.

Comment: Don't have much experience with oracle, but this looks promising: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files

Comment: 200k+ rows is actually not large. I query a table with 16 million+ rows using Python and pandas every day. The typical query completes in less than a second. If you have access to the table make sure it has an appropriate index for the fields you are querying.

Comment: you could give [dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469457/how-to-load-subset-of-large-oracle-table-into-dask-dataframe) a try

Comment: For the DB side of the problem, make sure a big arraysize is being passed down to cx_Oracle, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a tool which does better functions than Excel.

When you work with LargeData, you need the database connection from Python.

The answer to your question, which one is your application.
Search in https://pypi.org/
And install some pip package as ...SQL...

Depending on the package it will give the sentences of SQL.
Sometimes you can write as SQL in different methods, and in others, you will have simplified methods.

In my case I used SQLAlchemy.

Regards.