# How to connect to oralce database and import the data into csv format using dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe, dask-ml

---

How can I connect to oracle database using dask and fetch the data from it and create a csv file using the fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a SQL table into a Dask DataFrame with `dask.dataframe.read_sql_table`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469457/how-to-load-subset-of-large-oracle-table-into-dask-dataframe) should help you create a Dask DataFrame from an Oracle table.

You can use `to_csv` to write out CSV files after creating the DataFrame.

It'll look something like this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_sql_table(...)
ddf.to_csv(...)
```